# TrueCrypt 7.1a - resume encryption process

Tags: truecrypt

I have fully encrypted my system drive, but had to go back to a restore point (Win 7) before the disk was fully encrypted - thus it seems TrueCrypt thinks the process of encryption has to be resumed, hence getting the following message each time Windows starts:

> You have scheduled the process of encryption or decryption of the
>   system partition/drive. The process has not been completed yet. Do you
>   want to start (resume) the process now?

And when I click Yes, I get this:

> There is no process/task to resume.

When I go to System -> Encrypt System Partition/Drive I get this message:

> Your system partition drive seems to be fully encrypted.

Meaning the drive is indeed encrypted and everything is OK.

Is there a way to tweak some setting file of TrueCrypt so this prompt doesn't appear any more?

All I was able to find is a translation file here:

https://github.com/syglug/truecrypt/blob/master/Common/Language.xml#L963

Lines 962 and 963 are of interest:

```
<string lang="en" key="SYSTEM_ENCRYPTION_RESUME_PROMPT">You have scheduled the process of encryption or decryption of the system partition/drive. The process has not been completed yet.\n\nDo you want to start (resume) the process now?</string>

<string lang="en" key="ASK_NONSYS_INPLACE_ENC_NOTIFICATION_REMOVAL">Do you want to be prompted about whether you want to resume the currently scheduled processes of encryption of non-system partitions/volumes?</string>
```

So I suppose the keys `SYSTEM_ENCRYPTION_RESUME_PROMPT` and `ASK_NONSYS_INPLACE_ENC_NOTIFICATION_REMOVAL` could somehow direct me to where the settings for this prompt are being kept, but that's as far as my knowledge got me.

Any ideas what could I do?

Could reinstalling TrueCrypt help and can that at all be done considering the system is encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else comes across this issue - I resolved the problem by deleting the following entry in the registry:

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\TrueCrypt Format`

It runs the following executable:

`"C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt Format.exe" /acsysenc`

Comment: This is handy to know if you start encryption from one account but then want to automatically resume it from another account